maven assembly zip missing dependency JARs
I have the weird behavior where when I run mvn verify maven-assembly-plugin it produces different results compared to mvn deploy in CI.
I am using the following assembly descriptor:
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.2.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.2.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.2.0.xsd">

    <!-- providers with extra dependencies -->
    <id>providers-extra</id>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>

            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

            <includes>
                <include>com.example:module</include>
            </includes>

            <binaries>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>

with mvn verify it produces a ZIP file with modules JAR and it's dependency JARs.
but with mvn deploy it produces a ZIP file with just the module JAR.

This appears to be a problem with assembly plugin 3.6.0, after upgrading to 3.7.1 the problem is gone, it seems 3.6 and older have some problems with dependency scopes (MASSEMBLY-1008).
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

upgrading to 3.7 will also uncover potential previous scope problems, so double-check your module dependencies if you see unexpected JARs in the assembly ZIP.
Note you can debug mvn deploy locally my providing an alternate deploy repo using a file:// URI to "deploy" to filesystem:
mvn deploy "-DaltDeploymentRepository=local::file://$PWD/m2.dist/"

